How to add a background to the site identity logo
How can i change the background for my site identity?
I have the logo in the middle with just the regular white color background. I want to add some background to it. How do i fix that?
homepage
Tried to add some CSS classes but had no results

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

CSS rule that sets a logo link background (color copied from .navbar):
#wrapper-header .custom-logo-link {
  background: #343a40;
}




To expand it to .container:
#wrapper-header .container {
  background: #343a40;
}




Or to apply the background to a whole #wrapper-header:
#wrapper-header {
  background: #343a40;
}



Thanks this works for the color, now i also found the way to choose a image as background. Thank you very much!!
